# Why won't journalctl show logs when the program output is piped?

Tags: systemd, docker-compose, journalctl

I'm trying to run my docker-compose containers via a systemd service, and have fail2ban read their logs. However, docker-compose adds a prefix like:

`container_name_1    | Actual log message`

So what I'm trying to do is something like `docker-compose up --no-color 2>&1 | sed 's/^[^ ]*  *| //'` to strip that prefix so that fail2ban can match on the log lines correctly. But when I do that, I only see `Started mydockercontainers.service` in the journalctl logs. Removing the pipe to sed fixes everything.

How can I remove this prefix and keep the log messages in the journal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most programs including sed will use block buffering, not line buffering, when their output is something else than an interactive tty device. (For services, the stdout is a pipe and you would see a similar effect with `sed | cat`.)

This means output will be delayed while it accumulates in the buffer – it will only be written in chunks of 10-20 lines or so (however many fit in a 4kB buffer). Use the `sed -u` or `--unbuffered` option to disable the buffering.

In cases where the program doesn't have such an option, wrap it with `stdbuf -i0 -o0`.

Comment: Thanks! Glad the solution was so simple :)